# Screenshots on plugin page taken old

Tags: plugin-development, images

In readme before latest release they where named as:

> 1. BlaBlaBla
> 2. BlaBlaBla

Files also named in same pattern: screenshot-01.png, screenshot-02.png

After latest release only screenshot-10.png updated — other not!

And most interesting: on plugin page url of the image is https://ps.w.org/wp-testing/assets/screenshot-1.png?rev=1073672 (old image). But if you try manually https://ps.w.org/wp-testing/assets/screenshot-01.png?rev=1073672 — it will show new image.

I dont' think it's a caching issue — as screens from 10 are showed.

**UPDATE 1**. Open https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-testing/screenshots/ <strike>you will see old (previous) screenshots</strike>. But in trunk already new. So they should be shown new. See this commit: there are new texts and images updated: https://github.com/garex/wp-testing/commit/e73c7b5472cfe11fa435ec4c8b292a29e57c05ee

**UPDATE 2**. Problem was in showing old screenshost on plugin page. Solution is to actually remove screenshot-1.png from SVN to allow it using placed there already screenshot-01.png

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is? I don't get it.

Comment: @kraftner, updated

Comment: Are you commenting regarding any specific extension?

Comment: sounds like you should ask the wordpress.org support people, there is not much that people here know about how that site operates.

Comment: @MarkKaplun do you know where to contact them? :) WP has tons of different "Support" links, but I dont' see those gold link like "report bug".

Comment: @gaRex sorry, not sure, but maybe try the plugins and hack forum and people there might give a better direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason was simple: "wp-plugin-in-github" tool has not any delete assets functions. So in git repo there were no screenshot-1.png, but in svn repo — it was.

See: https://github.com/sudar/wp-plugin-in-github/blob/e5a004052342cbdfc5bd7fbcb844fffce8695f91/deploy-plugin.sh#L231

Workaround to work:

```
find $SVNPATH_ASSETS -type f -not -path '*.svn*' -delete
cp $GITPATH/$ASSETS_DIR/* $SVNPATH_ASSETS # copy assets */
cd $SVNPATH_ASSETS # Switch to assets directory

svn status | grep "^!" > /dev/null 2>&1 # Check if deleted assests exists
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    svn status | grep "^!" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn delete # Remove new assets
fi

svn status | grep "^?\|^M" > /dev/null 2>&1 # Check if new or updated assets exists
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    svn status | grep "^?" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add # Add new assets
fi

svn propset svn:mime-type image/jpeg *.jpg
svn propset svn:mime-type image/png *.png

svn status | egrep "^ ?(A|M|D)" > /dev/null 2>&1 # Check if we have somethign staged
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        svn commit --username=$SVNUSER -m "Updated assets"
        echo "[Info] Assets committed to SVN."
    else
        echo "[Info] Contents of Assets directory unchanged. Ignoring it."
fi

# Let's remove the assets directory in /tmp which is not needed any more
rm -rf $SVNPATH_ASSETS
```